# Couldn't read path d value from d3 json file?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I am reading an Arc information from json file and visualizing them using d3.
Actually I am using `d3.layout` to grouping data. so I have to read this file where `tag` is our `svg` tag that is `path` and the `value` is the `d` value of path ,The problem is d value will be changed after reading and return  `0`  . How do I read the `value`? Should I organize my json file differently? 
Here is my code :

The json file:

```
      {"id": "svgContent","children": [
         {"id": "circle1","tag": "path",
         "value": "M0,160A160,160 0 1,1 0,-160A160,160 0 1,1 0,160M0,100A100,100 0 1,0 0,-100A100,100 0 1,0 0,100Z",
    "children": [
        { "id": "point", "cx": "-67.59530401363443", "cy": "-93.03695435311894" },
        { "id": "point", "cx": "-109.37149937394265", "cy": "35.53695435311897" },
        { "id": "point", "cx": "1.4083438190194563e-14", "cy": "115" }
   ]

},
        {"id": "circle2","tag": "path","value": "M0,260A260,260 0 1,1 0,-260A260,260 0 1,1 0,260M0,200A200,200 0 1,0 0,-200A200,200 0 1,0 0,200Z",
    "children": [                
        { "id": "point", "cx": "-126.37382924288177", "cy": "-173.93865379061367" },
        { "id": "point", "cx": "-204.477151003458", "cy": "66.43865379061373" },
        { "id": "point", "cx": "2.6329906181668095e-14", "cy": "215" }

    ]

}

 ]}
```

This is my source code :

```
  var w = 1200, h = 780;
  var svgContainer = d3.select("#body").append("svg")
           .attr("width", w).attr("height", h).attr("id", "svgContent");
     var pack = d3.layout.partition();
   d3.json("/data.json", function(error, root) {

    if (error) return console.error(error);
    var nodes = pack.nodes(root);  
    svgContainer.selectAll("pack").data(nodes).enter().append("svg")
   .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; }).append("path")
   .attr("d", function (d) {

    console.log(d.value);

    return d.value; })
   .attr("transform", "translate(600,0)");

   });
```

When I checked the console I expected `"M0,260A260,260 0 1,1 0,-260A260,260 0 1,1 0,260M0,200A200,200 0 1,0 0,-200A200,200 0 1,0 0,200Z"` but it's return  `0` ,How can I handle it?

Comment: Your data is nested... I suggest creating a JSFiddle so we can manipulate your code.

Comment: From your code it's quite hard to guess what you want to do.
First of all `pathPack` is undefined. Maybe you meant `pack` ?
If you want to use the `d3.layout.partition` you probably want to create some sunburst diagram? Then don't have to write the path data into the json. Just place the values in the json and crate the path by using `d3.svg.arc()`. [Here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout#children) is an example for the json you could use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I don't have any value or some things else to create arc, I just have a 'json' file and need to read that. There was a wrong code that I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm not quite sure if your `d3.select("#body")` should maybe be a `d3.select("body")`? Or do you have an element with id `body`?

The problem with reseting the `value` to 0 is, that the `d3.layout.partition()` uses the value field. You could rename your value field to something else like `path`and set it with

```
.attr("d", function(d){
  return d.path;
})
```

Another problem with your code is, that you add several svg elements.
If you really just want to read the circle paths and display them, then this code does the job:

```
var w = 1200, 
    h = 780;
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("id", "svgContent");

d3.json("/data.json", function(error, root) {

  if (error) return console.error(error);
  svgContainer.selectAll("path")
      .data(root.children)
      .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("d", function(d) { return d.value})
      .attr("transform", "translate(260,260)");
});
```

No need for the partition layout. Just create path elements and add the path from the json.
If you want to show the circles, it would be better to place them outside of the pathelements in your json, because you can't add svg circles inside of path elements.